# How to Set UID with eXist-db 2.2 XMLDB-embedded java API

Tags: java, exist-db

I am updating an Exist-db XMLDB-embedded application from exist 1.4 to 2.2 using Java 1.8.
The User class has been deprecated in 4.4, so I am using UserAider instead, however the UserAider class does contain the setUID method.
How do I go about assigning a UID to a user?

I am attempting to use the following code to create a user and assign a UID, but the final line is Invalid.

```
user = new UserAider(username);
user.setPassword(password);
String[] groups = {"user"};
user.setGroups(groups);
user.setUID(-1);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UID's are not user modifiable in eXist 2.x. They are auto-assigned and managed by the system

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. As the User class is now an interface and is deprecated, should i be using the UserAider class to create users or should I be using some other class?

Comment: `UserAider` is the class to use at the moment.